# Laravel not recognized after .htaccess changes

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, redirect, laravel-4

Here is the baffling sequence of events that just transpired.

1) I have a working Laravel installation, with an **empty** `.htaccess` file, all URLs work.

2) I add some rules to `.htaccess` just to play around a bit, then remove the rules.

3) Now I have an empty `.htaccess` again (so nothing has changed compared to step 1 above) but now no URLs work anymore except the homepage.

For example, you will see that http://jovansprojects.com/march_madness/ works (that's the root of the Laravel folder), using this route:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
```

But http://jovansprojects.com/march_madness/login does not work anymore, despite having worked normally before.

This is the relevant route:

```
Route::get('login', 'SessionsController@create');
```

Note that it doesn't throw a Laravel error, like a 'not found exception' - it simply doesn't seem to know Laravel is installed there at all.

I've tried clearing Artisan's cache according to some online suggestions but didn't help.

So, to sum up: `.htaccess` is exactly the same as it was before (empty) but it seems the server doesn't even know to ask Laravel to handle the URLs anymore, not beyond the homepage anyway.

These are the rules I added to, and then removed from, .htaccess (I wanted to redirect trailing slashes):

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /march_madness/

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I suspect that `RewriteBase` may have something to do with it, but after I deleted the rules why didn't it revert to the way it was?

Comment: Did it "work" when you had those .htaccess directives? And just to confirm... you have _completely_ removed that file? Or you have an empty file - literally _nothing_ in it? Where is this .htaccess file - in the document root?

Comment: No, it didn't work with the htaccess directives (to be honest I don't even understand them, I copy/pasted from a different SO question). There is literally nothing in the file, just as there was nothing when it used to work. I tried deleting the file completely as well, same issue remains. The file is located in Laravel's root (march_madness).

Comment: By itself, adding and removing those directives in .htaccess should not have any lasting effect. So, there must either be some other caching mechanism or _something else_ was changed?

Comment: If there's a caching mechanism at work, it must have been installed by default, because I didn't add it. Any ideas? Nothing else was changed from my end.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Laravel, but how does it route "pretty" URLs without anything in .htaccess? I would have thought you would at least need the "Front Controller" bit?

Comment: Easy, in `Route::get('login', 'SessionsController@create');` it says that /laravel_dir/login should call the `create` method of `SessionsController`, which in turn can load views etc.

Comment: Yes, but how does the web server (I assume Apache) know what script to call in the very beginning? That's normally what the front controller does (by routing all unknown requests through `index.php`). Some PHP file needs to be called _before_ Laravel knows how to route the request (eg. `index.php`). To test this, the following URL appears to work: `/march_madness/index.php/login` (notice the `index.php` in the URL - this uses PATH_INFO to pass the request to `index.php`). This implies that the front controller in .htaccess _is required_ in order to create "pretty" URLs - like you have above.

Comment: Well now I feel dumb. There were two .htaccess files in different directories and one had the instructions to allow URLs without the "index.php". It's an easy fix now. Thanks for preventing me from wasting any more time on this :) If you add an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that Laravel does need the "Front Controller" in .htaccess in order to be able to route "pretty" URLs (ie. without having to use `index.php` in the URL and rely on PATH_INFO).

So, at the minimum, something like the following would be required in the .htaccess file (probably in the root of your Laravel install):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It would seem that there were two .htaccess. Note that .htaccess files are inherited along the filesystem path. However, mod_rewrite (to which the directives above belong) is not inherited by default. So, if you enable the rewrite engine in a subdirectory then the mod_rewrite directives in the parent directory will be ignored.